# Using more times the same CustomDrawableView (java class)

Tags: android, android-layout, view, crash, android-drawable

I create a java class that extends View, in the Main Acitivity I initialize more CostumDrawableView, but I would like to use the same CostumDrawableView (example: greenDrawableView) twice or more times, it's possible? 
How can I do?

If I write "greenLayout2.addView(greenDrawableView);" the activity doesn't open and crashes.
Thanks

```js
package com.example.prova.shaperectprove;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.RectShape;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.text.style.RelativeSizeSpan;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class CustomDrawableView extends View {

    private ShapeDrawable mDrawable;
    int x,y,width,height,drawColor;

    public CustomDrawableView(Context context,int drawColor,int left,int top,int right,int bottom) {
        super(context);

        mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
        mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(drawColor);

        mDrawable.setBounds(left,top, right, bottom); //limiti rispetto all'activity
        //left,top,right,bottom
        
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       
        mDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }

    protected void changeColor(int newColor) {

        drawColor = newColor;
    }

    protected int getLenght()
    {
        return width-x; //right-left
    }

    protected int getHight()
    {
        return height-y; //bottom-top
    }

    protected int mygetLeft()
    {
        return x;
    }
    protected int mygetTop()
    {
        return y;
    }

    protected int mygetRight()
    {
        return width;
    }

    protected int mygetBottom()
    {
        return height;
    }


    protected void changeSize(int x, int y,int width, int height){
        mDrawable.setBounds(x, y, width, height); //limiti rispetto all'activity
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

```js
package com.example.prova.shaperectprove;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.RectShape;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LinearLayout parent,myfirstLayout,mysecondLayout;
    private LinearLayout redLayout,greenLayout,blueLayout,redLayout2,greenLayout2;
//    Resources res = getBaseContext().getResources();
    ShapeDrawable myshape;
    CustomDrawableView greenDrawableView,greenDrawableView2;
    CustomDrawableView redDrawableView,redDrawableView2;
    CustomDrawableView blueDrawableView;
    Canvas mycanvas = new Canvas();

    final private static String str = "Green";
    final private static int idG = 1;
    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        parent = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        parent.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        parent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        myfirstLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        myfirstLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100));
        myfirstLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        mysecondLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        mysecondLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100));
        mysecondLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams myLLP = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams myLLP2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 100);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams myLLP3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 100);

        redLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        redLayout.setLayoutParams(myLLP2);
        redLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        greenLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        greenLayout.setLayoutParams(myLLP3);
        greenLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        blueLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        blueLayout.setLayoutParams(myLLP);
        blueLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        redLayout2 = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        redLayout2.setLayoutParams(myLLP2);
        redLayout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        greenLayout2 = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        greenLayout2.setLayoutParams(myLLP3);
        greenLayout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        
        blueDrawableView = new CustomDrawableView(this,0xFF68AEF0,10,10,100,80);
        greenDrawableView = new CustomDrawableView(this,0xFF1A9316,0,10,300,80);
        redDrawableView = new CustomDrawableView(this,0xFFC12727,0, 10, 200, 80);

        greenDrawableView2 = new CustomDrawableView(this,0xFF1A9316,10,10,300,80);
        redDrawableView2 = new CustomDrawableView(this,0xFFC12727,0, 10, 200, 80);

       
        greenDrawableView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                MyDialogGreen dialogGreen = new MyDialogGreen();
                dialogGreen.show(fm, str);
            }
        });

        redDrawableView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                MyDialogRed dialogRed = new MyDialogRed();
                dialogRed.show(fm, str);
            }
        });

        blueDrawableView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                MyDialogBlue dialogBlue = new MyDialogBlue();
                dialogBlue.show(fm, str);
            }
        });

        greenLayout.addView(greenDrawableView);
        redLayout.addView(redDrawableView);
        blueLayout.addView(blueDrawableView);



        myfirstLayout.addView(blueLayout);
        myfirstLayout.addView(greenLayout);
        myfirstLayout.addView(redLayout);
        parent.addView(myfirstLayout);

        

        greenLayout2.addView(greenDrawableView2);
        redLayout2.addView(redDrawableView2);

        mysecondLayout.addView(greenLayout2);
        mysecondLayout.addView(redLayout2);
        parent.addView(mysecondLayout);

        setContentView(parent);


        }

}
```

Comment: instead of extending `View` just create a custom `Drawable` class (class D extends Drawable)

Comment: @pskink Does this change resolve my problem?

Comment: yes, you will be able to use the same `Drawable` in multiple places

Comment: Thanks! I prove immediately!

Comment: @pskink In this way I can't use layout.addView(myDrawable), I don't understand maybe, can you help me? Thanks again.

Comment: ok,  maybe i didn't follow your ideas,  you want some multiple layouts to look the same,  right?  i mean they should have the sane background ?

Comment: I would like to have one main layout (parent) that includes all screen, it must contain more Linear Layout (myfirstLayout and mysecondLayout), they,instead, contain other layout (blueLayout,redLayout etc.) which must have a CustomDrawableView. Do you undestand? Maybe I explain badly.